# How to find a word before matching string

Tags: c#, regex

through to stack-overflow questions but didn't get the proper answer.
I need a separate Regex for before & after a matching string.

**1) Find word After a specific phrase/word** (this one working fine)

```
  var regex = new Regex(@"(?:" + mytext + @"\s)(?<word>\b\S+\b)");
```

**2) Find word Before a specific phrase/word** (not working)

```
 var regex = new Regex(@"(?:\S+\s)?\S*" + mytext  + @"\b\S");
```

> mytext="xyz"
>
> Input="this is abc xyz defg"
>
> output should be like that
>
> 1) for first,which is working
>   **xyz defg**
>
> 2) second, which is not working
>
> **abc xyz**

Comment: Consider using `string.Format` for your regex to make it a little more readable. The @ and + and " make it tricky to parse.

Comment: Like `@"(?<word>\b\S+\b)\s+(?:" + Regex.Escape(mytext) + @"\b)"`? Or `@"(?<word>\b\S+\b\s+)?(?:" + Regex.Escape(mytext) + @"\b)"` if you plan to force the word before optional.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for ur solution :) working now

Comment: Why don't you just use `.IndexOf()` and `.SubString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the whitespace between the word before and the keyword.

Also, for additional safety, I'd use a `Regex.Escape` with the `mytext` variable.

So, I suggest using

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<word>\b\S+\b\s+)?(?:" + Regex.Escape(mytext) + @"\b)");
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cword%3E%5Cb%5CS%2B%5Cb%5Cs%2B)%3F(%3F%3Axyz%5Cb)&i=this%20is%20abc%20xyz%20defg)

And to make sure we capture a whole word, you can use the following variation of the regex (since the `word` is optional, `\b` might be necessary):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<word>\b\S+\b\s+)?(?:\b" + Regex.Escape(mytext) + @"\b)");
                                               ^^
```

Answer (score 3):

Find word After a specific phrase/word

```
var regex = new Regex(mytext + @"\s\w+");
```

Find word Before a specific phrase/word

```
var regex2 = new Regex(@"\w+\s" + mytext);
```

Comment: This includes the text mytext too. How to write the pattern such that the match value only give the word before mytext and excludes mytext ?

Comment: You can try to delete mytext string from your result string. Replace function will help you. string replacedString = Regex.Replace(match.Value, mytext, "");