# I need to get a word before another one that always stay the same in string

Tags: c#, string

> In this text, swerve means:

I want the word before "means".  In the above text, I want the word "swerve". The word "means" is always at the same place, but the word before it changes.

How can I get the before "means"?

Comment: This question may not be a conventionally good one for stackoverflow but its title makes for excellent search terms for a very common task.

Comment: @hoodaticus if you are argumenting by this way, you should also know, we have the option to vote for [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717847/how-to-find-a-word-before-matching-string) (since most time good search titles have a duplicate). It shows only zero effort from the asker. (Already voted for to broad :()

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via Regex expressions like others mentioned in here, but I'd recommend a nuget package to add called "Sprache". Take a look at it [here](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache).

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
(\w+)(?=\W+means)
```

Or with full code:

```
string input = "In this text, swerve means";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)(?=\W+means)");
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(input)) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This will iterate through all matches it can find and print these words. It will furthermore print `"means"` twice in case you write `"means means means"`.

In the C# interactive shell, this generates:

```
csharp> string input = "In this text, swerve means";
csharp> Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)(?=\W+means)");
csharp> foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(input)) {
>     Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].(alue); error CS0103: The name `m' does not exist in the current context 
> }
swerve
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
string input = "In this text, swerve means:"; //your input string..

var word = Regex.Match(input, "In this text, (.+?) means:").Groups[1].Value;
```

or simple string ops like

```
var word = input.Split()[3];
```

Comment: Ok awesome! I think regex will work after all! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thank you, Regex worked and I need to learn more of this awesome class!

Comment: @Simon if you're new to RegEx understand it's a steep learning curve, perhaps try out *Verbal expressions* to get the hang of it...